# MemCache-using directed acyclic graph representing the dependencies of data?

Tags: facebook, memcached

I am reading the paper of memached from facebook. One part it mentioned that it reduces the latency by fetching maximum number of items concurrently. Here is the quote:

"We structure our web- application code to minimize the number of network round trips necessary to respond to page requests. We construct a directed acyclic graph (DAG) representing the dependencies between data. A web server uses this DAG to maximize the number of items that can be fetched concurrently. On average these batches consist of 24 keys per request."

What data here it refers to? Web page? Pictures? How it can have dependencies to other data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data required to show the web page. A post have dependencies on the poster, the images, the comments and many more things. And the comments have dependencies on the poster and so on